# Autoincrement based on a set of other columns

Tags: sql, db2

I have a table Course and every Course has many Resources.

```
Course
==========
course_id

Resource
==========
course_id
number
```

I want something like a separate autoincrement for each course_id. Or, in other words, I want to auto-enumerate the resources for a given course. For example, the resource table could look something like:

```
course_id | number
==================
1         | 1
1         | 2
2         | 1
1         | 3
1         | 4
2         | 2
2         | 3
```

and so on.
I want to do this *in SQL*, using IBM DB2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should let `Resource` pick its own ids...

```
resource_id | course_id
=======================
1           | 1
2           | 1
3           | 2
4           | 1
5           | 1
6           | 2
7           | 2
```

...and discover the rank via queries:

```
SELECT course_id,
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
          FROM Resource
         WHERE resource_id < r.resource_id
       ) + 1 AS rank
  FROM Resource r
```

This is undoubtedly more work for the optimiser, but will simplify life dramatically in every other respect (e.g., handling deletions).

Comment: To make it easier, when reading the table, how about an insert trigger that set's the course_id based on 'select max (number)+1 from Resource where course_id=<course_id of inserted item>' I am not sure if you can do this operation if you have a key over Course_id and number, but you can always go with the resource_id too.